# Turn the Caps Lock LED on, while keep Caps Lock status is off

Tags: keyboard, capslock

I have a *magicforce smart 68 kb* now and it would look better if the Caps Lock LED would emit light too.

I do not even has a Caps Lock function on that button, because I have switched it with the left Control, and made that to be a compose key for the international layout. I was searching and trying some stuff but nothing has worked so far.

tl;dr: How do I turn on the Caps Lock LED without enabling Caps Lock?

Comment: crosspost https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/45vysi/turn_the_caps_lock_led_on_while_keep_caps_lock_off/

Answer (score 12):

You can get a list of all controllable LEDs by checking the content of the virtual directory `/sys/class/leds`:

```
$ ls /sys/class/leds/
input5::capslock  input5::numlock  input5::scrolllock
```

On my system, there are only the three keyboard LEDs. If your output looks different, make sure you use the correct names instead below!

Each file is a symbolic link to a directory holding several properties of that LED:

```
$ ls '/sys/class/leds/input5::capslock'
brightness  device  max_brightness  power  subsystem  trigger  uevent
```

---

The only thing which is important for us is the `brightness` file content.

- `0` means the LED is off.
- `1` means the LED is on. (Assuming the `max_brightness` file holds the value 1 - on special keyboards the LED might maybe support multiple brightness values?)

---

We get the current LED state by checking the `brightness` file's content (it's currently off):

```
$ cat '/sys/class/leds/input5::capslock/brightness' 
0
```

To switch the LED on, we must set that file's content to `1`:

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee '/sys/class/leds/input5::capslock/brightness'
1
```

---

To switch the LED on during every boot, you might want to append the command below to your `/etc/rc.local` script. It will be executed as root, therefore we don't need the `sudo tee` but can use Bash output redirection:

```
$ echo 1 > '/sys/class/leds/input5::capslock/brightness'
```

Comment: Taking into account what you pointed out about the `max_brightness` thing, wouldn't a more complete solution to be simply cat out the value of the `max_brightness` file instead of either 0 or 1 everytime? For example:

```
echo `cat /sys/class/leds/<MY-LED>/max_brightness` | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/<MY-LED>/brightness
```

Comment: Possibly, although for keyboard state LEDs like CapsLock, personally I haven't seen any keyboards that have more states than just on/off. Other types of lighting such as the keyboard or screen backlight are likely to have a max_brightness > 1 and support multiple brightness levels. You can of course dynamically use the max_brightness value instead of 1, I assume for nearly all cases it's the same.