# How to set capslock LED color

Tags: keyboard, 20.10

I have a keyboard with an LED on caps lock, which can be on (white), off (... off) and it can be red if it is on low power.

In "`/sys/class/leds/input4::capslock/`" there is a file called `brightness` which is 0 or 1 to say if the light is on or off.

Is it possible to set the keyboard LED to red, and if so, how?

Comment: Are you sure it is "imput"?  `/sys/class/leds` will hold all available options and if there is nothing to switch it to red... there is a list here: `/sys/class/leds/*/trigger` Also interesting: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/leds/leds-class.html

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just made a typo, it is `input` not `imput`. 
/trigger does have a list:
`[none] usb-gadget usb-host rfkill-any rfkill-none kbd-scrolllock kbd-numlock kbd-capslock kbd-kanalock kbd-shiftlock kbd-altgrlock kbd-ctrllock kbd-altlock kbd-shiftllock kbd-shiftrlock kbd-ctrlllock kbd-ctrlrlock disk-activity disk-read disk-write ide-disk mtd nand-disk cpu cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 cpu4 cpu5 panic bluetooth-power rc-feedback hci0-power rfkill0 audio-mute audio-micmute phy0rx phy0tx phy0assoc phy0radio rfkill1 r8169-100:00:link r8169-100:00:1Gbps r8169-100:00:100Mbps r8169-100:00:10Mbps`

Comment: You already [tried `echo 1 > '/sys/class/leds/input4::capslock/brightness'`](https://askubuntu.com/a/734861/349837)? Or other values. Check also [`setleds`](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Setleds_command)

Comment: those are triggers than are checked to switch led status. I don't see a trigger for low-power. phy0rx is ethernet. phy0accoc is an accespoint. Oh and add that comment to the quesiton please ;)

Comment: Just a question. Is that wireless keyboard and red indicator is for keyboard's battery, or is that eg. laptop keyboard and indicator is for low power of whole device? Because if it's wireless keyboard, it could be that red LED is not programmable at all.